# Defining 500 initial random positions of an rotating object in 2-D by Python

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, 2d

I have edited my question. Now I don't want to use loop in my function. The function is for defining initial position of an rotating object in 2-D. I would like to get the output format like this:

`theta1 theta2 theta3
 phi1 phi2 phi3
 eta1 eta2 eta3`

The definition of e inside the function must be something else (my opinion). Can anyone help me to get my desired output?

```
def randposi(N=500):    
    theta = 2*pi* rand()-pi
    phi = arccos(1-2* rand())
    eta = 2*pi*rand()-pi
    r = random.rand(N)
    e = 3*r*array()
    return e
```

Comment: Are you looking for performance? `"good suggestions about how to do this?"` - Not exactly clear on what you are going for.

Comment: You keep using `rand()`, where is it defined? The line `if rand() < 12` doesn't make much sense to me (usually random generators generate numbers between `[0, 1]`)

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question and codes.

Comment: What does rand() do? in particular what do you expect `rand(N)` or `rand(500)` as you hard code N=500 to return?

Comment: So you recommend me to use rand(N=500)?

Comment: @Biophysics now it's completely unclear what you want.

Comment: The only thing I can guess that you are using is the random library as rand. Therefore your code would resemble `import random as rand` then you can use `rand.random()` to produce a random number between 0 and 1. you can then change it to whatever range you require with `N*rand.random()` But I think you need to give us more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a random numpy array ?

Something like that:

```
import numpy as np
N=500
#we create a random array 3xN
r = np.random.rand(3,N) 
#tetha is row 0, phi row 1, eta row 2
#we apply the same treatment that is in the question to get the right range
#also note that np.pi is just a predefined float
r[0]=2*np.pi*r[0] -np.pi
r[1]=np.arccos(1-2*r[1]) 
r[2]=2*np.pi*r[2] -np.pi

print(r[0],r[1],r[2])
```

Comment: @Biophysics I just meant "your" treatment. Sorry if it was unclear, I slightly modified the comment.

Answer (score 0):

So if we make your function return a tuple:

```
def randpos():
    theta = 2*pi* rand()-pi
     if rand() < 12:
         if phi < pi:
            phi += pi
         else:
             phi -= pi
      eta = 2*pi*rand()-pi
      return (theta, phi, eta)
```

then call it 500 times and put the results in a list of tuples.

```
starting_pos = []
for x in xrange(500):
    starting_pos.append(randpos)
```

And you have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension for this, for your case:

```
def randpos(N=500):
    # your function code here
    ...

desired = 500
init_positions = [randpos() for i in range(desired)]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you've defined your function f(x) called randpos, it seems this function doesn't accept any input. N is the variable you'll use to iterate over this function, you got few options here:

You can store your values in some list like this:

```
N = 10
random_positions = [randpos() for i in range(N)]
print random_positions
```

If you don't need to store values you just loop through them like this:

```
for i in range(N):
    print randpos()
```

If you prefer instead, you just yield your values like this:

```
def my_iterator(N=500):
    for i in range(N):
        yield randpos()

for rand_pos in my_iterator(N):
    print rand_pos
```